# Can not remove Google+ button

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site and am using the plugin 'Yet Another Social Plugin' to add social buttons at the end of each post. The problem is on my mobile site which I have customized with WP-Mobile is showing these buttons. I am able to remove all of them except the G+ button. I am able to get it removed using visibility: none; when I do a live edit inside of Chrome developer console but when I apply that in the css it is ignored and I am not even seeing it when I view that tag/class. Is there some trick or something weird about the +1 button that I am missing?

You can view a picture of the issue here, https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11217802/Screenshot_2013-04-28-00-07-03.png

and a good 'test page' is here,
http://jrummy16.com/test/app-manager-overview/

Our test site is currently jrummy16.com/test. I am just spoofing my User agent to view it on my computer.

Comment: try selector {display: none !important;} or selector {position: absolute !important; visibility: hidden !important;}

Comment: there is no none value for the visibility property. it's visible, hidden, collapse or inherit

Comment: @Jawad Can you tell me how to control that property? I tried the display tag and it did not remove it.

Comment: I just told you. selector {visibility: hidden !important;}

Comment: @Jawad Sorry I missed that and it is currently what I have been using which is not working. Thanks for the input though

Comment: what's not working? For example in here http://jrummy16.com/test/project/ultimate-backup/ just add .Qo {display: none;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit

Sorry, I didn't see that you were talking about your mobile site.

In this case, add

```
.plusone{
    display: none;
}
```

to your CSS - it will hide the entire iframe.

<strike>As your G+ "`a`" as no ID nor class, edit your css to add</strike>

```
.socialmedia-buttons a:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
```

Consider using `display:none;` rather than `visibility:hidden;`, as the `visibility` property holds the placeholder of your div while `display` suppress it of the flow.

Visibility:hidden; => 
[image]

This should do the trick (tried with Chrome inspector on [this page](http://jrummy16.com/test/?post_type=post)).

Comment: Hey @bigood thanks for that but it is the wrong set of buttons. I should have been more clear as to what I am trying to do. We only want the buttons removed on the mobile side. The buttons we are wanting to remove are located on pages like this, http://jrummy16.com/test/app-manager-overview/ under the video. You can view a picture I took of the page on my phone here, https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11217802/Screenshot_2013-04-28-00-07-03.png

Thanks for the info on 'display:none' will be very helpful in the future!

Comment: @aDroidman I was updating my answer when you were writing your comment, I just noticed that. Please refer to my edited answer

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you very much. It would have taken me forever to figure out that I needed to use display: none instead of visibility: hidden.

Comment: I should quit my habit of answering in comments. +1 for not being a lazy mule like me